# Is there a view that can show time entered per day?

Tags: org-mode, time-date

Basically I am after a method to find missing times.

Currently I use this code to view times per task.

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :link t :maxlevel 10 :block week :scope file
```

But I can not view if i am missing times with in any particular day.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `:step day` option:

`#+BEGIN: clocktable :step day :stepskip0 nil :link t :maxlevel 10 :block week :scope file`

From the docs:

`:step day` => to split the table into chunks by day. To use this, :block or :tstart, :tend are needed.
`:stepskip0 nil` => explicitly keep empty days in the clocktable (this is the default, though)

Further reading about clocktable options: 
http://orgmode.org/manual/The-clock-table.html